Links in WKWebview not showing numbers when "Show Numbers" command is activated with Voice Control
I am using WKWebview and loading HTML content with couple of anchor  tags to open another view in app itself when tap on link. However, I do not see any numbers for links when I say "Show Numbers" with voice control turned on.
Any help would be appreciated. I am testing it with 17.4.1
